# java.net.SocketException: Socket closed on CentOS (Linux)

Tags: java, linux, sockets, proxy

I have a java application which uses an internal proxy server to analyze http trafic for a web application (in browser - Prism or Chrome/Chromium) which is in fact a  part of the same app. Based on the trafic analysis it executes some actions...

The application runs well in Windows (XP, 7 and 8) and I also use it in without any problems in Ubuntu and Suse. Recently a new potential client wanted to test it in CentOs, but I been getting java.net.SocketException: Socket closed. 
Following code produces this exception (implements Runnable):

```
   public void run() {
    try {
        // create a server socket, and loop forever listening for
        // client connections
        synchronized (this) {
            server = new ServerSocket(thisPort);
            notifyAll();
        }
        while (true) {
            if(server.isClosed()){ // I added this just to see if it helps...
                server = new ServerSocket(thisPort);
            }
            Socket client = server.accept();  // Exception thrown here

            ProxyThread t = new ProxyThread(client, fwdServer, fwdPort); // new Thread takes care of comunication, no issues there at all...
            t.setDebug(debugLevel, debugOut);
            t.setTimeout(ptTimeout);
            t.start();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
            debugOut.println("Proxy Thread error: " + e);
            e.printStackTrace();

    }

    closeSocket();
}
```

Trace:

```
java.net.SocketException: Socket closed
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketAccept(Native Method)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.implAccept(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.accept(Unknown Source)
    at sk.tido.simpleproxy.Proxy.run(Proxy.java:20)
```

System info:

```
CentOS release 6.3 (Final)
Linux pcpanel 2.6.32-279.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Jun 22 12:19:21 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I tested it with 2 versions of java namelly:

```
java version "1.7.0_60"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_60-b19)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.60-b09, mixed mode)

java version "1.6.0_24"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea6 1.11.1) (rhel-1.45.1.11.1.el6-x86_64)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.0-b12, mixed mode
```

Any suggestions are welcomed as app has been running without issues for nearly 2,5 years in other Linux distros...
I was only able to find similar issues like my, but related to httpclient on the net, which didn't help me much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're closing the ServerSocket somewhere else in your application while this code is blocked in accept().

Comment: Your answer made me look into the code from other holistic perspective. I have found out that other thread closes the socket. But this is not a bug in my code, it is work as designed. Later on I found out that there is an issue with Chromium on that platform and it won't start there. Therefore; my code was not able to start it and thread responsible for checking whether browser is running ended   proxy thread (closed socket). Then whole app closed normally... I was searching for a bug on wrong place and I didn't thought that Chromium might be problem...